# Как эмулировать нажатие на кнопку в приложении WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, button

Подскажите, как в приложении WPF эмулировать программно нажатие на кнопку Button левой клавишей мыши?
Использовать button1.PerformClick() не предлагать, в WPF нет такого метода у Button.

Comment: Можно узнать зачем вам это понадобилось?

Comment: Да, конечно. Есть несколько объектов Button на форме. Они могут быть нажаты кнопкой мыши. Или же нажатием на определенные клавиши клавиатуры (например, цифры 1, 2, 3 и т.д.). При нажатии мышью визуально видно на какой объект Button нажали. Если же нажать кнопку клавиатуры, этого не видно. Поэтому нужно эмулировать нажатие на Button

Comment: Попробуйте вызывать функцию кнопки напрямую из кода. Если функция одна - получайте кнопку и ищите соответсвия

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Способ 1:**

```
this.button.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
```

**Способ 2:**

```
typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase)
.GetMethod("OnClick", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
.Invoke(button, new object[0]);
```

**Пример:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("КНОПКА НАЖАТА");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.button.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase).GetMethod("OnClick", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(button, new object[0]);
    }
}
```

[image: Программно нажать кнопку]

Comment: Спасибо. Оба способа работают. К сожалению, ни один из них не решает проблемы. Так как метод "OnClick" вызывается, но визуального выделения кнопки как при нажатии кнопкой мыши нет.

Answer (score 2):

В шаблоне кнопки есть элемент `ButtonChrome` (называется `Chrome`), нажатие по кнопке с помощью триггера выставляет свойство `RenderPressed` этого элемента в значение `true`. Вы можете добавить кнопке Attached Property и переопределить ее шаблон, в котором добавить еще один триггер на установку этого AP.

Более простой, но менее изящный способ — наследоваться от кнопки и выставить публичный метод для ее нажатия:

```
class MyButton : Button
{
    public async void PressAsync()
    {
        var chrome = GetTemplateChild("Chrome") as Decorator;
        if (chrome == null) return;
        var chromeType = chrome.GetType();
        var propertyInfo = chromeType.GetProperty("RenderPressed");
        propertyInfo.SetValue(chrome, true);
        await Task.Delay(100);
        propertyInfo.SetValue(chrome, false);
    }
}
```

Я здесь использовал рефлексию, т.к. `ButtonChrome` может использоваться из разных сборок (зависит от ОС и от ее темы).

Использование:

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBox Margin="10,0,10,5" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
    <c:MyButton x:Name="MB" Content="Click me" Padding="10,2"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Кодбихайнд:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MB.PressAsync();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Другой, еще более костыльный способ — использовать вместо обычной кнопки переключатель `ToggleButton`:

```
class MyButton : ToggleButton
{
    protected override async void OnChecked(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnChecked(e);
        await Task.Delay(100);
        IsChecked = false;
    }
}
```

При нажатии кнопки в поле ввода просто установите ему `IsChecked = true`, через 0,1 с он "откинется" автоматически:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MB.IsChecked = true;
}
```

Comment: Попробовал вторым способом. Не работает. Никаких ошибок не выводится, но никакой визуальных изменений при вызове PressAsync() не происходит. Вы уверены, что такой способ будет работать в приложении WPF?

Comment: Попробовать первым способом не получилось - не нашел в шаблоне кнопки элемента ButtonChrome

Comment: Конечно будет, именно WPF и есть. У вас Windows 10? Если так, то скажу вам по секрету - на Win10 у кнопки нет визуализации нажатия :) Есть только наведение.

Comment: @АлексейШокарев, попробуйте еще один костылик, добавил в ответ.

Comment: Да, у меня Windows 10. Визуализация наведения вполне подойдет. Пробовал тупо менять цвет фона кнопки, устанавливая свойство Background. В принципе работает. Но мне нужно его устанавливать из обработчика событий таймера System.Timers.Timer. Тут возникает ошибка, потому что обработчик таймера по-видимому исполняется в другом потоке. Использовать же другой тип таймера, который совместим с оконным интерфейсом не могу, так как он не обеспечивает необходимые мне настройки. В принципе проблему б решил корректная установка свойства Background кнопки из обработчика таймера. Возможно ли это реализовать?

Comment: Не понял,зачем тут таймер, я же показал вам как делать. ToggleButton тоже не подходит (работает на Win10, только что проверил)? Для доступа к контролам из другого потока надо использовать диспетчер: `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => MyButton.Background = ...)` Если вы не в коде формы, то диспетчер можно получить из `Application.Current.Dispatcher`

Comment: *не нашел в шаблоне кнопки элемента ButtonChrome* - хм, да, на Win10 там в шаблоне просто `Border`, поэтому мой код эффекта не дает, он просто выходит из метода здесь: `if (chrome == null) return;` Но визуализация нажатия там все же есть

Comment: Андрей NOP, cпасибо, предложенный вариант доступа к контролам из другого потока решил все проблемы. Таймеры нужны для другого - по ним через заданный интервал времени выполняется нужная команда. Таким образом, остановился на варианте в обработчике клавиатуры подсвечивать кнопки цветом, а затем по срабатыванию таймера возвращать подсветку обратно.

Comment: @АлексейШокарев, запускать каждый раз таймер - плохочитаемое решение, используйте `await Task.Delay`. Можно вынести в отдельный `void` (не `Task`, а именно `void`)-метод и в нем сделать `Background = ...; await Task.Delay(...); Background = ...;` (в общем-то как у меня в ответе примерно)

Comment: Не могу понять как вставить код в комментарий. Но если кратко, то у меня используется не один таймер, а массив таймеров (около 50 штук). Каждый из которых запускается по нажатию соответствующей кнопки на форме или клавише клавиатуры. И срабатывает через определенный интервал времени. Соответсвенно, меняется подсветка связанной с ним кнопки. Возможно это можно реализовать и через Task.Delay(), но мне показалось, что код с таймерами проще в понимании и надежней. Кроме того, при попытке вставить Task.Delay() в код обработчика клавиатуры возникает ошибка что метод не async.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77182/discussion-between--nop-and--).

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще вот такой способ:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();             
        }

        /*Вспомогательные методы и константы...*/
        public static Point ElementPointToScreenPoint(UIElement element, Point pointOnElement)
        {
            return element.PointToScreen(pointOnElement);
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int smIndex);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs,
           [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), In] INPUT[] pInputs,
           int cbSize);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Win32Point pt);

        const uint MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000;
        const uint MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001;
        const uint MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
        const uint MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;
        const int SM_CXSCREEN = 0;
        const int SM_CYSCREEN = 1;        

        /* Эмулирует нажатие мышью на элемент управления */
        public static async void PerformClick(Control ctrl)
        { 
            double XSCALEFACTOR = 65535.0 / (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - 1);
            double YSCALEFACTOR = 65535.0 / (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - 1);

            //находим координаты центра элемента
            double x = ctrl.ActualWidth / 2;
            double y = ctrl.ActualHeight / 2;
            Point p = ElementPointToScreenPoint(ctrl, new Point(x, y));            

            //сохраняем текущие координаты мыши
            Win32Point mouse = new Win32Point();
            GetCursorPos(ref mouse);            

            //эмулируем нажатие
            INPUT[] arr = new INPUT[1];            
            arr[0].Type = INPUT_TYPE.INPUT_MOUSE;
            arr[0].Data.Mouse.ExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
            arr[0].Data.Mouse.X = (int)Math.Round(p.X * XSCALEFACTOR);
            arr[0].Data.Mouse.Y = (int)Math.Round(p.Y * YSCALEFACTOR);
            arr[0].Data.Mouse.Flags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
            var res =SendInput(1, arr, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)));            

            if(!Window.GetWindow(ctrl).IsMouseOver)
                await Task.Delay(1); //если мышь за пределами окна, WPF понадобится некоторое время для обработки события

            //возвращаем предыдущее положение мыши
            arr[0].Type = INPUT_TYPE.INPUT_MOUSE;
            arr[0].Data.Mouse.X = (int)Math.Round(mouse.X * XSCALEFACTOR);
            arr[0].Data.Mouse.Y = (int)Math.Round(mouse.Y * YSCALEFACTOR);
            arr[0].Data.Mouse.Flags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE ;
            res = SendInput(1, arr, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)));
        }

        private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //пример использования
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            PerformClick(button1); 
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            PerformClick(button2);
        }  

    }

    //WINAPI types...

    enum INPUT_TYPE : uint
    {
        INPUT_MOUSE = 0,
        INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1,
        INPUT_HARDWARE = 2
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
     struct INPUT
    {
        public INPUT_TYPE Type;
        public MOUSEKEYBDHARDWAREINPUT Data;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
     struct MOUSEKEYBDHARDWAREINPUT
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public HARDWAREINPUT Hardware;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public KEYBDINPUT Keyboard;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public MOUSEINPUT Mouse;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
     struct HARDWAREINPUT
    {
        public uint Msg;
        public ushort ParamL;
        public ushort ParamH;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
     struct KEYBDINPUT
    {
        public ushort Vk;
        public ushort Scan;
        public uint Flags;
        public uint Time;
        public IntPtr ExtraInfo;
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
     struct MOUSEINPUT
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
        public uint MouseData;
        public uint Flags;
        public uint Time;
        public IntPtr ExtraInfo;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
     struct Win32Point
    {
        public Int32 X;
        public Int32 Y;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WPF

```
ButtonAutomationPeer bap = new ButtonAutomationPeer(Button); 
IInvokeProvider iip = bap.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) 
as IInvokeProvider; 
iip.Invoke();
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]